# prevent event on target and it's parent

Tags: javascript

I have this code which i use to remove a classname "joker" from every element that has this classname: http://jsfiddle.net/ffz30knn/1/

Is it possible (with vanilla JS only) to prevent this event on the target element and it's parent, so when i click `<span class="joker">one</span>` which is inside `<div class="joker"></div>` it will remove the "joker" class from other elements that has this class but not from this span element and it's wrapping div?

Thanks.

Here is the current code:

```js
function removeClass(classToRemove) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);
  console.log(elems.length);
  if (!elems) return;
  for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)joker(?!\S)/g, '');
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.onclick = function() {
    removeClass("joker");
  };
};
```

```css
div {
  background: silver;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  margin: 5px;
}
span {
  background: blue;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: white;
}
.joker {
  background: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one two three joker"><span class="joker">one</span>
</div>
<div class="one two three"><span>two</span>
</div>
<div class="one two three joker"><span class="joker">three</span>
</div>
<div class="one two three"><span>four</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want to delete the class `joker` from every element BUT the one you clicked?

In your `removeClass` function you can check if it is the same element

```
function removeClass(classToRemove) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);
  console.log(elems.length);
  if (!elems) return;
  for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    if(elem != this)
        elem.className = elem.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)joker(?!\S)/g, '');
   }
}
```

And I guess you can check for the parent element by doing `Element.parentElement`, so that would give you:

```
if(elem != this && elem != this.parentElement)
```

Comment: you have to use  event.target instead of "this" in the last line, "this" is the current element which received the event which would be the document object

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element you've clicked through the onclick event:

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.onclick=function(event) {
        removeClass(event.target, "joker");
    };
};
```

Pass that to your function and you should be able to achieve what you desire.

```
function removeClass(skip, classToRemove){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);
    if (!elems) return;
    for (var i=elems.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        if (elem == skip || elem == skip.parentElement) {
           return
        } else {
            elem.className = elem.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)joker(?!\S)/g,'' ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffz30knn/7/)

Comment: This isn't dealing with that parent.

Comment: I was actually clicking the div, therefore i had to capture it's child `<span class="joker"></span>`. replacing `.childNodes[0]` by `.parentElement`will have the disired effect then.